# Chave estrangeira em WebApi com dotnet core

Tags: c#, json

Seguinte estou criando uma webapi(Estou usando o Entity Framework) com duas classes, Curso e Disciplina, onde a disciplina tem o Id de um curso, criei da seguinte forma:

```
public class Curso
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public List<Disciplina> Disciplinas{ get; set; }
}

public class Disciplina
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public int CursoId { get; set; }
    public Curso Curso{ get; set; }
}
```

O método OnModelCreating está assim:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Disciplina>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Curso)
            .WithMany(p => p.Disciplinas)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.CursoId);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

No banco de dados criou certo, Curso possui Id e Nome e Disciplina possui Id,Nome e CursoId, porém quando eu faço as requisições GET's o resultado é o seguinte:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "SI",
    "disciplinas": 1,
  }
]

[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "POO",
    "cursoId": 1,
    "curso": null
  }
]
```

Há alguma forma de do Entity mapear melhor para que essas chaves que estão vindo NULL não apareça no JSON?

Lembrando que preciso apenas o Id do curso na disciplina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Há alguma forma de do Entity mapear melhor para que essas chaves que
>   estão vindo NULL não apareça no JSON?

Para ignorar objetos nulos é necessario configurar isso na `Startup.cs`, você pode fazer da seguinte forma

```
services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        });
```

Pode ser que seja preciso baixar o pacote `Newtonsoft.Json`

Para isso, no *Package Manager Console* execute o comando **`Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json`**

Comment: Deu certo, valeu!

Answer (score 0):

No `Entity Framework Core`, você não precisa criar a propriedade para a chave estrangeira. Basta fazer:

```
public class Curso
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public List<Disciplina> Disciplinas{ get; set; }
}

public class Disciplina
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public Curso Curso{ get; set; }
}


protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Disciplina>().HasOne(p => p.Curso);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Curso>().HasMany(p => p.Disciplinas);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Quando for selecionar os dados, não esqueça do include:

```
_context.Cursos.Include(x=>x.Disciplinas).ToList();
```

Comment: Eu tinha feito dessa maneira, porém quando iria fazer um POST na disciplina, eu não conseguia passar apenas o ID do Curso, tinha que passar a estrutura inteira do objeto. Se eu não passasse o objeto Disciplina iria toda NULL